# SQL, How to retrieve a column only once associated with multiple entries of same value in another column?

Tags: sql

Suppose following a table named 'SalesRecords'

```
Name     City        Sales     Item
John     London      10        X
John     London      5         Y
John     New York    7         Z
Charles  London      5         A
George   New York    10        A
Geroge   New York    5         X
```

Here John is the same person in London and in New York, what I want is to retrieve a person who work in more than one city, as well as which cities they work in and correspoding no. of sales they have made in that city. Like follows -

```
Name     City        Sales
John     London      15
John     New York    7
```

How to achieve this using SQL?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use GROUP BY on Name and City:

```
SELECT a.Name, a.City, SUM(a.Sales) AS Sales
FROM yourTable a

INNER JOIN (
            SELECT NAME, COUNT(*)
            FROM
                (
                SELECT Name, City
                FROM yourTable
                GROUP BY Name, City
                )
            HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
            ) b ON A.name = b.name

GROUP BY a.Name, a.City
```

Comment: That will also retrieve George who trades only in New York which is intended to be excluded.  Only that person who works in multiple cities should be selected.

Comment: True! Edited to include HAVING clause

Comment: It selects as follows
```
Name City           TotalSales
John London   15
George New York   15
```

Comment: Oh yes, more complex than I first thought. Third time lucky joining to a subquery to identify multiples...? Answer edited.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exists` before aggregation:

```
SELECT Name, City, SUM(Sales) as TotalSales
FROM SalesRecords sr
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM SalesRecords sr
              WHERE sr2.Name = sr.Name AND sr2.City <> sr.City
             )
GROUP BY Name, City;
```

Or, you can use window functions:

```
SELECT nc.*
FROM (SELECT Name, City, SUM(Sales) as TotalSales,
             COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Name) as Num_Cities
      FROM SalesRecords sr
      GROUP BY Name, City
     ) nc
WHERE Num_Cities >= 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

I use common expression table to achive value of TotalSales and then in query I filter person who worked in more than one city.

```
;with sales as
(
    SELECT 
        Name,
        City, 
        SUM(Sales) as TotalSales
    FROM SalesRecords
    GROUP BY Name, City
)
select name, city, TotalSales from sales s
where exists(select * from sales s2 where s2.Name = s.Name and s.City <> s2.City)
```